# Webfaction 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

Tags: email, webfaction

I have a problem with my email address (exemple@mydomain.com). On webmail.webfaction.com, I success to send email to exemple@gmail.com, but when I reply, I have 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. It's the same when I write directly an email from example@gmail.com to exemple@mydomain.com.

My web site is hosted by webfaction. I readed all of documentation https://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/email.html but I haven't any solution's idea.

I choose just "Save to local mailboxes" and I created automatically one. The first time I logged in, I wrote exemple@mydomain.com on webmail.webfaction.com.

If somebody could help me :)

Comment: If you get such an error from the mailserver of your hoster, you'd better ask your hoster about that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed :)
if it can help somebody, my domain is hosted by 1&1 (redirected on webfaction servers) and I had not configured MX on 1&1. That's why, my emails were stopped by 1&1.